# Trigger Jenkins Build on Database Change

Tags: database, build, triggers, hudson, jenkins

As the subject suggests I'm interested in triggering Jenkins on changes involving a pre-configured database table. For example, whenever the number of records changes I want Jenkins to perform some particular action. Is there a plugin out of the box available for this scenario?

Thank you!

Regards,
Alex

Comment: As far as i know not...but does your database have the oportunity to trigger an URL get request ?

Comment: Unfortunately the database is unable to trigger GET requests...

Comment: What about running a Jenkins job which checks every 5 Minutes etc. contents of the database which would mean in your case select count(*) table ...and save the value in the workspace of Jenkins and every time it changes you can trigger an other job ...

Comment: I have never tried this myself, is there any kind of documentation you could refer me to? thx!

Comment: Either you have a command line client for your database or you can write a script (perl, ruby, Groovy, Java whatever) to get this functionality. This script can be executed by Jenkins. Based on the absence of information about which database we are talking about i can't give you a more detailed hint. Furthermore it wouldn't be a problem to ask Google...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you have a command line client for your database or you can write a script (perl, ruby, Groovy, Java whatever) to get this functionality. This script can be executed by Jenkins. Based on the absence of information about which database we are talking about i can't give you a more detailed hint.

Answer (score 0):

What database are you using?
Most of them have some kind of triggers that can be fired after table insert, update or delete.

Comment: This is the same solution as proposed by @khmarbaise. Actually I don't know the database, yet (this is more of a conceptual question), hence I was looking for a solution that does not rely on triggers.

Answer (score 0):

A logical alternative to database triggers is polling: write a script that will poll the database and store the results you are watching. If they change the script can modify a file which will trigger a Jenkins build via [FS Trigger plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/FSTrigger+Plugin).

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to use a [ScriptTrigger](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/ScriptTrigger+Plugin), which can easily use embedded Groovy or Shell/Windows Batch script to pool database with a query to verify state of the given data.